# Web Service Exception: "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialise the message"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, entity-framework, parsing

Got a question. I get this error and I know it is due to the fact that int32 has a number limit of 2147483647. But I don't know why I am getting this error when the value in question (a telephone number of 11 digits) is defined as a string in our SQL database, a string in our web service and a string in our web application.

I assume it is something to do with the way the service serialises and deserialises data over a connection, but I was wanting to know if there is a way to force Number to use only the string instead of parsing it when deserialisation happens. Or even get it to parse as int64.

Here is the error exception. I removed the namespace and service name. It is the property Number that is causing the problem.

> There was an error deserializing the object of type .".ClientPhone[]. The value '07721545554' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'."

And here is the code for the service and the service interface.

```
[DataContract]
public class ClientPhone
{
    [DataMember]
    public int? ClientNumberID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? RefID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string NumberType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool? PrimaryNumber { get; set; }
}

    public partial class ClientNumberEntity
{
    public int ClientNumbersID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RefID { get; set; }
    public string ClientNumberType { get; set; }
    public string ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PrimaryNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ClientDataEntity ClientData { get; set; }
}

public List<ClientPhone> GetClientsPhoneByReference(int _reference)
    {
        OurDatabaseEntities context = new OurDatabaseEntities();
        var phoneEntity = (from c in context.ClientNumberEntities
                           where c.RefID == _reference
                           select c).ToList();
        if (phoneEntity != null)
        {
            return TranslateClientPhoneEntityToPhoneNumberList(phoneEntity);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Unable to get phone data");
    }

private List<ClientPhone> TranslateClientPhoneEntityToPhoneNumberList(List<ClientNumberEntity> numberEntities)
    {
        List<ClientPhone> phoneList = new List<ClientPhone>();
        foreach (ClientNumberEntity numberEntity in numberEntities)
        {
            ClientPhone phoneListMember = new ClientPhone();
            phoneListMember.ClientNumberID = numberEntity.ClientNumbersID;
            phoneListMember.RefID = numberEntity.RefID;
            phoneListMember.Number = numberEntity.ClientNumber;
            phoneListMember.NumberType = numberEntity.ClientNumberType;
            phoneListMember.PrimaryNumber = numberEntity.PrimaryNumber;
            phoneList.Add(phoneListMember);
        }
        return phoneList;
    }
```

Any advice on a solution would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution, albeit it's more stupidity on my end.

I didn't realise that my .EDMX entity diagram hadn't been updated with the new values from the database (I had to manually delete the entity and re-add it to force changes).

After re-compiling and updating the service reference, it worked.